# More than one round bracket in function call?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, currying

I have an exercise where I need to write a function. Function scheme look like

```
auto add(int a){
}
```

I need to be able to call this function with many brackets:

```
add(1)(2)(3); // 6
add(1)(2)(3)(4); // 10
add(1)(2)(3)(4)(5); // 15
```

But I can not figure out which C++ feature I should use in this case. I heard that I should use functors but I don't know if this is the best idea in this case.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Why do you think you need to call it like that?

Comment: You could return a  function pointer to itself

Comment: @M.M function pointer won't work - it would have to maintain state somewhere.

Comment: @M.M: There's an old "Guru of the Week" column by Herb Sutter proving you can't. You can't even declare that function: it's signature is made up of its arguments and its return type, and its return type must contain the signature. That's unbounded recursion.

Comment: @MSalters [O rly?](https://wandbox.org/permlink/uVA7w1l1jxAu6J2I)

Comment: @M.M return values in comments (`// 6`, `// 10` and `// 15`) imply that state (partial sums) has to be maintained somewhere. Without having to return anything useful, then yes, you could return function pointer.

Comment: @M.M: Yeah really. Each function template instantiation is a unique function with a unique return type. There is a dependency graph, in that the type of `adder<n>` depends on the type of `adder<n-1>`. But that obviously is a non-cyclic dependency graph, with `adder<0>` as the single root. The case of a function `f` returning `&f` is a special case of a cyclic dependency graph with cycle size 1, and therefore impossible. Using the same cyclic dependency graph, you can show that `f` can't return `&g` if `g` returns `f` (cycle length 2).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do it by having `add` return a [functor](http://cpp.sh/86hfj), i.e., an object that implements `operator()`. You can write a templated version that will let the compiler deduce the type. Try it [here](http://cpp.sh/86hfj).

```
template <class T>
struct adder 
{
    T val;

    adder(T a) : val(a) {}

    template <class T2>
    auto operator()(T2 a) -> adder<decltype(val + a)> { return val + a; }

    operator T() const { return val; }
};

template <class T>
adder<T> add(T a)
{
    return a;
}
```

### Example

In this example, `T` will ultimately resolve to `double`:

```
std::cout << add(1)(2.5)(3.1f)(4) << std::endl;
// T is int -----^
// T is double ------^
// T is still double -----^
// T is still double ----------^
```

Here is another example where `T` will resolve to `double`:

```
std::cout << add(1)(2.5f)(3.1)(4) << std::endl;
// T is int -----^
// T is float -------^
// T is double ------------^
// T is still double ----------^
```

### Explicit Constructor

If you want the constructor of `adder` to be `explicit` you also have to change the return statements slightly.

```
template <class T>
struct adder 
{
    T val;

    explicit adder(T a) : val(a) {}

    template <class T2>
    auto operator()(T2 a) -> adder<decltype(val + a)>
    {
        return adder<decltype(val + a)>(val + a);
    }

    operator T() const { return val; }
};

template <class T>
adder<T> add(T a)
{
    return adder<T>(a);
}
```

Comment: I would make the constructor `explicit` to remove ambiguities

Comment: Sure, that will also slightly change some return statements. @Mot

Comment: @Motti I added an example which use an `explicit` constructor. But I can't come up with a good example where the `explicit` constructor is required.

Comment: @Jonas, I can't either off the top of my head, if `adder<T>` was used from outside `add` it would be easier to show such cases.

Comment: How can I perform same with JavaScript. Please help if you can.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that comes to my head is make this "add" as some class object with overloaded brackets operator, which will return new object, and then call new brackets from it, but you will need to return final value from it somehow, like some getter func.

```
class Adder{

private:
    int value;
public:
    Adder():value(0){}
    Adder(int a):value(a){}
    int get(){return value;}
    Adder operator() (int a) {
        return Adder(value+a);
    }
};
```

But it doesn't seem as something useful, probably there is better way to accomplish what you want to get.

Comment: You should add operator int() {return value;}